# How do you naturally find a set of images that are statistically independent?

Tags: correlation, independence

I am trying to search for a set of images that are statistically independent (or have little correlation) with each other. I went on google images and picked out random images shown below thinking that they would be independent of each other:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

However, when I input these images into MATLAB and compute the correlation coefficient between all the images, I get the following correlation matrix:

```
1.0000    0.3142    0.2012    0.1075    0.0743
0.3142    1.0000    0.2028    0.2375    0.0144
0.2012    0.2028    1.0000    0.0534    0.0442
0.1075    0.2375    0.0534    1.0000    0.6505
0.0743    0.0144    0.0442    0.6505    1.0000
```

The diagonal elements are obviously 1.000 since an image is always highly correlated with itself. However, to my surprise, I am seeing high correlation numbers in off-diagonal elements of the matrix! For example, look at row 5, column 4 = 0.6505.  This is saying the 4th image (a hill with shrubs) is correlated with the 5th images (skyscrapers).

I need to find a set of pictures whose correlation matrix is less than 0.2 in all the off-diagonal elements.

I did some [research](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101802-how-can-i-generate-two-correlated-random-vectors-with-values-drawn-from-a-normal-distribution) and found out I can use Cholesky Decomposition to generate new matrices (or images) with your desired correlation.  However, if I do this, the uncorrelated images I will generate will not look like anything in real life.  So, I'm wondering if it's possible to find independent images naturally?

Comment: What is interesting is that all your correlations are positive.  The fourth and fifth less so (light sky, darker foreground) but the first and second more so.  What would happen if you calculated the correlation between an image and its negative?

Comment: @Henry - Yes, I took the absolute value of the correlation coefficient because I'm more interested in the magnitude, not the "direction".

Comment: Many photographs have a contrast between foreground and background, and that is probably driving your non-zero correlations in your first set, unlike the patterns across the images in your second set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use fractal images shown below and was successfully able to get a correlation matrix with off-diagonal correlations much less than the desired 0.2.

```
1.0000    0.0222    0.0207    0.0186    0.0126
0.0222    1.0000    0.0328    0.0255    0.0082
0.0207    0.0328    1.0000    0.0073    0.0273
0.0186    0.0255    0.0073    1.0000    0.0040
0.0126    0.0082    0.0273    0.0040    1.0000
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]